# How to exclude data based on other conditions

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to create a formula based on the following.

A5 = ward (e.g. 14, 15 or 16)
I5 and J5 are providing dates patient transferred offsite and to home
If I5 and J5 are blank then I want to be able to add the fact we still have a patient in this ward, once the date is added to either I5 or J5 I want the 14, 15 or 16 to be excluded.

Based on this formula, I want to be able to show how many patients I have left in 14, 15 and 16 and a total at the end.

Answer (score 0):

this formula will give you how many is left in ward 14 (data from a5 to A13 in my example): `=COUNTIFS(A5:A13,14,I5:I13,"",J5:J13,"")`

It counts all occurences of 14 in A column, blank in I column and blank in J column. (You can add similar formulas for wards 15 and 16 and add a sum as well.)

Comment: thank you Tom, you are a star, much appreciated